# Is it possible to merge multiple Kinect streams using vision_opencv?

Tags: ros, kinect, opencv, ros-hydro, vision-opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently it came to my attention that in the later ROS versions much of the complex image processing/handling has been offloaded to other sources such as OpenCV.  The camera_pose_calibration package is hopelessly broken for later distros. I've recently stumbled on `vision_opencv` so I'm asking if anyone here has used OpenCV tos olve this problem.

I've got three Kinects which I've been using through ROS. I have the ability to access each of their depth/RGB streams through the usual code from the tutorial. However, I want to use RViz or something similar and merge the live streams into one 3D stream using a universal coordinate frame. I've read about using checkerboards and have done intrinsic calibrations with them. Conceptually, I know what to do but as far as coding, most of the repos I find are from 2011 and either deprecated or severely bugged.

Can anyone point me to tutorials or packages in which might help? I'm using two model 1473's and a 1414, so I'm not sure if I can get the 1473's to play nice but I should at least be able to get one 1473 and the 1414 to work.  I'm in a time crunch, and I need to be able to get these streams in RViz simultaneously.  The last few months I've hit a brick wall, so any knowledge would help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128436/is-it-possible-to-merge-multiple-kinect-streams-using-vision_opencv?/) by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2014-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[camera_pose_calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_pose_calibration) should do what you want. It isn't currently working in hydro though (not sure about groovy).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-02-12**:
See the part where I said "The camera_pose_calibration package is hopelessly broken for later distros."  I'm trying to find an alternate since using that package is a nightmare.  And I'm not interested in using Fuerte.

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2014-02-12**:
I don't think writing this from scratch will be any easier than bringing camera_pose_calibration up to date.